# Nested json to pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this json from request

```
{
    "count": 5175,
    "text_indicator_to_statistics": [
        {
            "text_indicator": {
                "type": "URL",
                "value": "some text"
            },
            "statistics": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-04-15",
                    "field": "CLICKS",
                    "value": 7.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-04-15",
                    "field": "POSITION",
                    "value": 4.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-04-15",
                    "field": "IMPRESSIONS",
                    "value": 8595.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-04-15",
                    "field": "CTR",
                    "value": 0.0
                },
```

I want to convert it into dataframe to have this table

| key | date | CLICKS | POSITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some text | 2023-04-15 | 7.0 | 4.0 |

So for 'key' i need to get value from "text_indicator" and add values from "statistics"

I both try this codes

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['text_indicator_to_statistics'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['text_indicator_to_statistics', 'statistics'])
```

but it gives me two diferent table that i can't combine together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
data = {
    "count": 5175,
    "text_indicator_to_statistics": [
        {
            "text_indicator": {"type": "URL", "value": "some text"},
            "statistics": [
                {"date": "2023-04-15", "field": "CLICKS", "value": 7.0},
                {"date": "2023-04-15", "field": "POSITION", "value": 4.0},
                {"date": "2023-04-15", "field": "IMPRESSIONS", "value": 8595.0},
                {"date": "2023-04-15", "field": "CTR", "value": 0.0},
                {"date": "2023-09-05", "field": "CLICKS", "value": 0.0},
                {"date": "2023-09-05", "field": "DEMAND", "value": 26.0},
                {"date": "2023-09-05", "field": "IMPRESSIONS", "value": 0.0},
            ],
        }
    ],
}


def get_statistics(s):
    out = {}
    for d in s:
        out.setdefault(d["date"], {}).update({d["field"]: d["value"]})
    return out


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"key": i["text_indicator"]["value"], "date": k, **v}
        for i in data["text_indicator_to_statistics"]
        for k, v in get_statistics(i["statistics"]).items()
    ]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         key        date  CLICKS  POSITION  IMPRESSIONS  CTR  DEMAND
0  some text  2023-04-15     7.0       4.0       8595.0  0.0     NaN
1  some text  2023-09-05     0.0       NaN          0.0  NaN    26.0
```

Comment: Can you help me one more time?

In my response code there is sevral date from response

    {'date': '2023-09-04', 'field': 'IMPRESSIONS', 'value': 0.0},
    {'date': '2023-09-04', 'field': 'DEMAND', 'value': 27.0},
    {'date': '2023-09-04', 'field': 'CTR', 'value': 0.0},
    {'date': '2023-09-05', 'field': 'CLICKS', 'value': 0.0},
    {'date': '2023-09-05', 'field': 'IMPRESSIONS', 'value': 0.0},
    {'date': '2023-09-05', 'field': 'DEMAND', 'value': 26.0},  

how can i get all this date for one key , because now it's only show me the first date - 2023-09-04